# python-find detect path file in string

Tags: python, string, file, path

I want the code to write to me all the paths in the text. for example:

```
text = "hello. this is path: C:\Users\zivsi\noz\wave.txt"
print(path in the text)
(C:\Users\zivsi\noz\wave.txt)
```

how can i do this?
thank you

Comment: Are you familiar with regular expressions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could probably attempt to find some file systems in your path. Assuming that all the paths that you want to find contains the file system. I will try to do it like this:

```py
file_systems = ["c:","d:","f:"] # Your possible file systems here
file_extensions = [".txt",".csv", ".xml"] # Your file extensions here

# my text
text = r"hello. this is path: C:\Users\zivsi\noz\wave.txt"

# The position where the path starts/ends
idx_fs = 0
idx_fe = 0 

for i in range(len(text)):
    test_fs = text[i:i+2].lower()
    test_fe = text[i:i+4].lower()
    # Find the position where your file system starts
    if test_fs in file_systems:
        idx_fs = i
    if test_fe in file_extensions:
        idx_fe = i + 3
        break

path = text[idx_fs:idx_fe]
print(path) # This gives as result: C:\Users\zivsi\noz\wave.txt
```

I know this has a limited use case, but it works with the path you provided, please let me know if this was what you were looking for! :D

Answer (score 0):

Try to use regex to match particular patterns in a string, see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) for the re library doc (the regex library).

Comment: can i get help? i don't know what should i use

Comment: What kind of help did you want ? Have you clicked on the "here" in my Answer ?

Comment: Yes, but I did not dislike your question

Comment: I don't know how to use regex

Comment: In regex, you have a pattern made of symbols (for exemple Dot "." means any character), and a text (your string), the re library allows you to search yout pattern in your string, and return the result.
In your situation, you can try this pattern "C:(\\\(.)*)*txt" → it search  "C:" followed by "\<anytext>" repeated as much as he wants, followed by "txt"